# How to replace Bootstrap with Semantic-UI for Aurelia's Starter Kit?

Tags: javascript, frontend, aurelia, semantic-ui

What changes are required to replace the `Bootstrap` with `Semantic-UI` for this Aurealia's Starter Template ([skeleton-typescript](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript))?

Comment: I have a blog on using Semantic-UI with Aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will read it. But based on @peinearydevelopment comments I think it would be nice to create one more Skeleton repository with Semantic-UI. I don't have enough experience to do that otherwise I would have created myself.

Comment: I can't speak for the rest of the team, but I am available for hire to help with training and development, such as this. If this is something you seriously need, please contact me on Gitter via http://gitter.im/davismj.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but am working on the experimental project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you mean, it is hard to answer. There are a number of different things you could be asking about.

Assuming that you just want to know how to switch out the packages and have the base css file loading, here is what you would need to do.

I manually removed the bootstrap entries from the `config.js` and the `package.json` files.

I assume you could accomplish the same by running the command `jspm uninstall bootstrap`.

I then ran the command `jspm install semantic-ui`.

There are two other changes you would need to make.

In `app.html`, change `<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>` to `<require from="semantic-ui/semantic.css"></require>`.

In `main.ts`, change `import 'bootstrap';` to `import 'semantic-ui';`

After making those changes, I can see the `semantic.js` and `semantic.css` files getting loaded by the browser in place of the bootstrap files. The page doesn't look nicely styled though as I didn't update any of the html elements to reflect semantic-ui's classes or element structure.

There are two other changes you will want to make for the build/bundle gulp tasks as well.

In `build/bundles.js`, change

```
"bootstrap",
"bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
```

to

```
"semantic-ui",
"semantic-ui/semantic.css!text",
```

In `build/export.js` change

```
'bootstrap', [
  '/fonts/*'
]
```

to

```
'semantic-ui', [
  '/themes/{THEME_NAME_OF_CHOICE}/*'
]
```

If that is what you are looking for, please be more specific with your question.

Hope this helps!